# iOS 6: Icons and launch application

Tags: ios, ios6, icons, launch, armv7

I've got a problem with my iPhone when I'm trying to run my application. I've got this message:

> "Could not launch “iNiveau PRO.app”
>   No such file or directory (/Users/jerrycor3/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iNiveau_PRO-gcxzxwcnetxnjubgctsnwjdsltcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/iNiveau PRO.app/iNiveau PRO)"

I tried all the solutions I have found on the internet, like quit XCode, move to trash the derived data folder, delete the application from my iPhone, restart it, etc... But nothing worked :/

I've got this problem yesterday when I tried to add an icon to my app. So I think there is a connection with this but I don't know what. I also tried to change amv7 to amv6 in the required system setting.

I don't know what's wrong...

Thank you and merry Christmas ! =)

Comment: Have you tried turning your Mac off and on again?

Comment: I've tried to turn off and on my session, but i really think the mess is coming from the icons i tried to put, because i've got a new message when i tried to put them. I really don't know how to fix it, and when you're finishing your app, it's just hard that nothings work...

Comment: I think you should try to turn your MAC off and on again. Sometimes the OS X's launch service may cause this problem. And this works on me.

Comment: I am not sure but try to remove space from project name and then run.

Comment: So I'm trying and we should see in a minute :)

Comment: Not working, i try but it's not work... :/ Too bad...

Comment: If anyone has got a solution, don't hesitate ! :/

Comment: Is this an error message from your iPhone, Xcode, or the iPhone Simulator?

Comment: It's from xcode : i've found a solution, make a new project, and it's work. I don't know where was the error but now it's work, sounds good :)